# how do i improve my website look in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

Here is my new website http://searchmyfile.com/ but when i open it in chrome browser its is very small text and images i want to show bigger then right now i have website width how do i set automatically adjust website width to every computer i want a bigger text and images which is fit to every computer can any one help me i am very sorry am very new person in web developing.

i have added two images

image 1: current look 
image 2: which i want to set by default in any one computer when it open

Comment: Try Ctrl+ keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

try http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp; i.e. use the font size attribute.

Go to your page, and in the `<head>`, add `<style> p { font-size:10 em;} </style>`. Change 10 for larger/smaller text.